# Not able to play many audio files in Android using MediaPlayer objects

Tags: android, audio, android-mediaplayer

I have a large list view. Each list view item has a play button (image). On clicking that play button it will play some small audio file.

I created an Adapter to load elements in list view and implemented onClick listener on play.

When I launch the application, it is loading list properly but there is some problem in audio. When I play few (like 10-12) items many times (like 100) it will not create any problem everything will run smoothly.

**But if I play more items like 30-40 items in the list. It stops loading audio files for later items. For items, it was working it will continue to work, for new items it don't work.**

[image]

```
    public class WordListAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    private ArrayList<Word> wordArrayList;
    private Activity activity;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    MediaPlayer mp;

    public WordListAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<Word> wordArrayList) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.wordArrayList = wordArrayList;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return wordArrayList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        if(convertView == null) {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_word, null);
        }

        TextView word1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.word1);
        TextView word2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.word2);
        ImageView imageWord = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageWord);
        ImageView playWord = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.playWord);

        word1.setText(wordArrayList.get(position).lang1);
        word2.setText(wordArrayList.get(position).lang2);

        if(wordArrayList.get(position).pic == 0) {
            imageWord.setVisibility(GONE);
        }
        else {
            imageWord.setImageResource(wordArrayList.get(position).pic);
        }

        playWord.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(activity, wordArrayList.get(position).audio);
                mp.start();
            }
        });

        return view;
    }
}
```

**I guess the problem is because I have created too many Media Player objects.**

How to fix it?

Comment: are you playing audio from your phone storage or streaming ?

Comment: From Phone. 

`MediaPlayer.create(activity, wordArrayList.get(position).audio)`

I am loading audio file from resources.

Comment: All the audio files (around 100) are there in resources.

Answer (score 1):

I once faced the similar problem, what did I do is to use service for playing media file . I am sharing what I did. Create a service like following

```
public class PlayMusicService extends Service
        implements MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener,  MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener {

    private int audioResource;
    public static MediaPlayer player;


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        audioResource = intent.getIntExtra("musicResource",0);
        player = MediaPlayer.create(this, audioResource);
        player.setLooping(false);
        player.setVolume(100, 100);
        player.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        player.setOnErrorListener(this);
        player.start();
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        player.stop();
        player.release();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
        this.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, int i, int i1) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then call this service  like following

```
        playWord.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(getActivity(),PlayMusicService.class);
               serviceIntent.putExtra("musicResource", wordArrayList.get(position).audio);
            }
        });
```

Let me know of if it works for you . One thing to be remembered here you might need to use a local broadcast manager for changing the view from your service.

Answer (score 1):

MediaPlayer uses system codecs, which will eventually come to an end if you do not release the previously created MediaPlayers. So try to call mp.release(). For example, try this (just i am not sure it will work - release itself):

```
playWord.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(activity, wordArrayList.get(position).audio);
            mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
               @Override
               public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                   mediaPlayer.release();
               }
            });
            mp.start();
       }
});
```